# Netty websocket close gracefully

Tags: android, websocket, netty

I need to make my websocket to close gracefully. Firstly send all messages that are waiting in buffer then close.

```
channel.flush();
channel.close();
```

seems not right, because I dont have any completion handler for flush method to do close after it is done.

Is there any way to do this.
Netty used: 4.1.0.Beta3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick you can use is to writeAndFlush an empty buffer, then attach a listener to that call.  [Unpooled.EMPTY_BUFFER](https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/buffer/Unpooled.html#EMPTY_BUFFER) can make this pretty easy.

```
channel.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.EMPTY_BUFFER).addListener(...
    channel.close();
)};
```

If all you want to do is close the channel after the flush then you can use [ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE](https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelFutureListener.html#CLOSE) to simplify your code.

```
channel.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.EMPTY_BUFFER).addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
```

If you do this often enough, then you may want to write a static helper method [like the Netty examples do](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/eb7f751ba519cbcab47d640cd18757f09d077b55/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/socksproxy/SocksServerUtils.java#L29).